# touch command create multiple files (different names) under one directory

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, brace-expansion

I wanted to make a script that creates a directories and files structure in bash.

I tried something like this:

```
"mkdir -p 1/2 && touch 1/2/{a b c}"
```

a,b,c should be files created in one command or something..

but for some reason the structure goes like this

```
current folder: b c 1

1: 2

2: a
```

touch can't be used to create multiple files with different names in one directory?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to add `,`:

```
mkdir -p 1/2 && touch 1/2/{a,b,c}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p 1/2 && touch 1/2/{a,b,c}
```

The commas are essential, otherwise it is evaluated to `1/2/{a b c}`.
Whitespace is only allowed in such patterns if it is escaped:

```
echo a{1\ 2\ 3,4} # echo a1 2 3 a4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like commas or need to create file names in sequential order, use '..'

```
mkdir -p 1/2 && touch 1/2/{a..c}
```