# how to create same multiple file in multiple dirrectory?

Tags: linux

suppose I have 3 dirrectories named dir1,dir2,dir3.And I want to touch 3 same files(f1.txt,f2.txt,f3.txt) in each dirrectories(dir1,dir2,dir3).how can I do that with one command?
dir1
-f1
-f2
-f3
dir2
-f1
-f2
-f3
dir3
-f1
-f2
-f3

Answer (score 1):

Simply use curly braces around the directories and files when creating the files with touch

```
touch {dir1,dir2,dir3}/{f1.txt,f2.txt,f3.txt}
```

Also see this question

[touch command create multiple files (different names) under one directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466014/touch-command-create-multiple-files-different-names-under-one-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question;

If you just need to create those 9 files in one command, simply use

```
touch dir1/f1.txt dir1/f2.txt dir1/f3.txt dir2/f1.txt ...
```